# What's the difference between App::singleton and bindShared?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, singleton, ioc-container

The Laravel docs indicate that the appropriate way to bind a singleton is with the `App::singleton()` method, but internally Laravel will use the `bindShared()` method (for example, in `TranslationServiceProvider`).

I assume that the documented approach is preferred, but is there a functional difference? If not, is there any reason for having two approaches (beyond maybe historical accident)?

Comment: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10921

Comment: That forum post is about the share() method, not the bindShared() method. The question seems to be fundamentally the same, but the answer there doesn't really address what I raise above. I know that the two methods are approximately the same; I'm looking to find out what the difference in nuance is and when/why one should be preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been wondering the same thing. I don't know the motivations behind this, but I can speak to a few differences.

Here is the definition of the two methods from Laravel 4.2:

```php
public function singleton($abstract, $concrete = null)
{
    $this->bind($abstract, $concrete, true);
}

public function bindShared($abstract, Closure $closure)
{ 
    $this->bind($abstract, $this->share($closure), true);
}
```

Similarities:

- Both methods call `bind()` under the hood.
- Both methods pass `true` to the 3rd parameter of `bind()`, which signifies that this is a shared object.
- In both cases, because this is a shared object, a call to `isShared($abstract)` will return true.
- In both cases, because this is a shared object, a call to `make($abstract)` will return *only* the first instance.

Differences:

- `singleton()` will accept a `Closure` or a `string`. `bindShared()` will only accept a `Closure`, not a `string`.
- `bindShared()`, in addition to binding the object into the IOC container as a shared object, takes the *additional* step of wrapping the passed `Closure` in a `share`'d `Closure`, which prevents the passed `Closure` from being executed more than once. At first glance, this appears to be a *double* assurance that the object will be treated as a singleton. I can only guess why this might be desirable.
- `bindShared()` is called 87 times inside the framework. `singleton()` is called 0 times.

Comment: Looks like all `bindShared()` calls have been changed to `singleton()` in Laravel 5.0 framework. The implementations of the two methods seems to be the same.

Answer (score 7):

They are (were) functionally identical, except that `bindShared()` only accepts closures.

Thus `bindShared()` has been deprecated in Laravel 5.1 ([PR 9009](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9009) - [commit 829060f](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/829060f521d03df34bc4053f911d58583f4eccd9)) and removed in Laravel 5.2 ([PR 9037](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9037)).

Case finally solved :)

Answer (score 2):

**bind($abstract, $concrete, $shared)**
Adds $abstract as a key to the container, with $concrete being the concrete class to instantiate in its place. Mainly used for providing a concrete implementation for an interface.

**share($closure)**
Given a closure (only), makes it act as if it was shared (instance/singleton style), and returns it. Technically equivalent to App::bind($key, $closure, true) but goes about it a different way. Mainly used in service providers to add a fully resolvable service to the IoC container.

**bindShared($abstract, $closure)**
A shortcut that was introduced in 4.1 that caters to a common pattern. Essentially helps those who want to bind a shared instance in the container. See below for example.

**singleton($abstract, $concrete)**
Simply an alias to bind with the $shared argument set to true. Mainly used for providing a concrete implementation for an interface, but one that should only have one instance (database connection, etc.)."

This is from http://alexrussell.me.uk/laravel-cheat-sheet/ I think this link should be helpfull

Comment: This explains indirectly that singleton() and bindShared() are the same, but it doesn't really answer the question of why there are two approaches. The article just says they "go about it in a different way." Well, yeah. But why? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think mainly for backwards compatibility. Singleton explains better behavior than bindShared. Removing bindShared would mean Package developers to refactor their code.